# Login button and auth dosnt work in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have some login code that works well for Firefox and other browsers, but it gives me an error when I use it in Internet Explorer. Help me.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/6HXmS/1/

Comment: you need to provide more details.  what is the error?  what are the steps for reproduction?  what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you're asking? Is this a programming question, or are you just having trouble logging in to facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have added all the required og:meta tags
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
   *also you have using the html5 version of the button but your document is not set to doc type html5, change doc type or, you could try the xfbml version of the button if all else fails.*
2. Try rendering the button after JS.sdk has loaded.

---

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <div id="loginbutton"></div>
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '136067339849637', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//www.crabiz.biz/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        }); 
    function loginbutton(){
    var loginb=document.getElementById('loginbutton');
    //loginb.innerHTML='';
    loginb.innerHTML=' <div class="fb-login-button" on-login="funx()" scope="email,user_likes,user_about_me,publish_stream,read_friendlists">
            Installa Artesposa
          </div><br>';
    FB.XFBML.parse(loginb);
    };
loginbutton();
    };
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));

    function funx() {    
        window.top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/Partecipazioninozze.Artesposa/app_136067339849637";    
        }
    function funxie() {    
        window.top.location.href = "https://apps.facebook.com/arte-sposa";    
        } 

    </script>
```